# Delete everything except what matches a regex pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string and I want to replace everything but the pattern.

Right now I know what I want to do is

```
$line =~ s/[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}//g;
```

but inverted so that it replaces everything with nothing except the pattern.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You should show the string and what you are expecting. And in your pattern what is this `{4]`?

Comment: Just correct your `{4]` to `{4}` and use round brackets as a matching group around your search expression sourrounded by `.*` to match the rest of the line outside the group, then insert a back reference in the replacement string like `\1` - it should look like  `s/.*([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}).*/\1/g;`.

Comment: Can you give some examples of input and output? Otherwise it's very hard to give a meaningful answer. I would suggest you don't really want to do that at all, and instead extract the pattern matches.

Comment: Do you mean: I have a pattern and I want to delete everything on a line except the *match* of the pattern? What if there is more than one match? What if there is none?

Comment: You have used the global `/g` modifier. Do you expect multiple occurrences if the pattern in the string, and do you want to retain them all?

Comment: To properly mark the question as answered you should put out the answer below among other answers and optionally accept it.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit unclear what you are asking, but you may wish to try something like the following, which captures the pattern and then replaces the line with the capture:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @lines = (
    'HELLO WORLD',
    'HELLO ABCD1234 WORLD',
    'HELLOABCD1234WORLD',
    'H E L LO ABCD1234 WORLD',
);

my $re_match = qr([A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4});

for my $line (@lines) {
    print "$line  => ";
    if ($line =~ $re_match) {
        $line =~ s|^.*($re_match).*$|$1|;
        print $line . "\n";
    } else {
        print "does not match pattern $re_match \n";
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
HELLO WORLD  => does not match pattern (?^:[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4})
HELLO ABCD1234 WORLD  => ABCD1234
HELLOABCD1234WORLD  => ABCD1234
H E L LO ABCD1234 WORLD  => ABCD1234
```

Comment: sorry for the unclear question.
I'm trying to process the line:
`<p>Prerequisite: A mark of 75 in COMP1911 and completion of the bridging course, or COMP1921, or COMP1917.</p><p><strong>CSS Contribution Charge:</strong>&nbsp;2&nbsp;<a href=...`

into the string COMP1911COMP1921COMP1927 (removing everything but the "course codes") so I can then again process them individually.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -E '$_="xxABCD1234xxABCD1234xx"; @m = $_ =~ /[A-Z]{4}[0-9]{4}/g; @m and $_ = join "", @m; say'
```

Output:

```
ABCD1234ABCD1234
```